# yum - find packages in version minimum 'x' in specific repository?

Tags: centos, redhat, yum, rpm

I have configured several repositories on my CentOS 5 box. As an effect, command:

```
yum search nagios
```

outputs just mess - thousands of duplicated packages.

To make my life easier I would like for example to search for package *nagios* only in specific repo, like rpmforge and with minimum version '3', for example.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=rpmforge list avaiable 'nagios-3*'
```

---

**UPDATE Tue Jul 10 18:04:26 ICT 2012**:

`# yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=rpmforge list avaiable nagios | awk '$2 >= 3 { print $0 }'`

Comment: It does not work as expected. It will show me packages only in version '3' but not in version 4 and 5.

Comment: Try the updated command that I've appended to my answer.

Comment: yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=rpmforge list avaiable nagios | awk '$2 >= 3 { print $0 }'